# Maintaining submenu visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display a submenu when the mouse is over the parent li BUT when I move the mouse to the submenu it disappears and this is not making sense to me.

I'm using jquery to do so.

Here's my code (shortened):

```js
function showSub(id) {
  $('#' + id).slideDown('fast');
}

function hideSub(id) {
  $('#' + id).slideUp('fast');
}
```

```css
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9B9A98;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .menu li a span {
    line-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  .menu li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.85);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .menu li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    list-style: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.php"><span>HOME</span></a>
  </li>
  <li onmouseover="showSub('atelier')" onmouseout="hideSub('atelier')">
    <a href="index.php?p=atelier"><span>ATELIER</span></a>
    <ul id="atelier">
      <li><a href="index.php?p=quem_somos"><span>QUEM SOMOS</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="index.php?p=portfolio"><span>PORTFOLIO</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't understand. Since the submenu is inside the `li` it should keep the submenu visible while the mouse is over it.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this jQuery snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu li").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children("#atelier").slideDown();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children("#atelier").slideUp();
        }
    );
});
```

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/t884g25b/

Comment: I did some arrangements and worked exactly as I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do that purely with CSS.

**CSS**

```
#atelier {
  display:none;
}
.menu > li:hover #atelier{
  display:block;
}
```

No JS required. The HTML remains the same. [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/z8khdnjo/)

If you want to get the animation, you might want to try out something like [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-drop-down-menu) OR [this](http://jsfiddle.net/elvbq/).

**Side Note -** The better practice is to **NOT** have event handler information in your HTML. To bind events, you can use methods like `addEventListener()`(Modern Browsers) or `attachEvent()`(Some Old IE versions).

With jQuery you become browser agnostic and let jQuery handle all browser compatibility internally. So you could just do..

```
$("YOUR_SELECTOR_HERE").on("EVENT_TYPE", function(event){
    //your event handler with the "event" details. 
})
```

There are different ways `.on` can be used. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I used to use only CSS but I want to add the sliding animation.

Comment: I appreciate the side note.